# Image not being retrieved from Dropbox

Tags: html, image, dropbox, src

Hi!
I have an image slider. When I try toe retrieve the images from my server, the images are properly displayed. (http://stthomasmountmtc.org/index.html)

However, when I try to retrieve the same images from Dropbox, the images are not displayed/retrieved. (http://stthomasmountmtc.org/index1.html)

```
 <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/woart55urbw792u/image1.jpg" alt="image" />
```

When I open the link in the `src` attribute in the browser, the images can be seen, so the link is obviously not broken. Please share your suggestions.

Thanks,
Samuel Mathews.

Comment: The https://www.dropbox.com/s/woart55urbw792u/image1.jpg is not an image, but a HTML webpage.

Comment: but i use the similar link for the other 6 images from dropbox but it gets displayed properly (when image url is given in css). please guide me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The link in your code opens the gallery feature of Dropbox, which is a HTML webpage, not an image file. The direct link for that image is:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/woart55urbw792u/image1.jpg

You should always set the source of an image tag in HTML to an URL which outputs an image - and not a webpage containing an image.

Answer (score 13):

Another option to view a Dropbox image directly is to access the Dropbox link using the **?raw=1** parameter.

For example, if the Dropbox link is:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/83dcx4efx791s2i/stackoverflow.png?dl=0
```

change the ?dl=0 to **?raw=1**, such as:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/83dcx4efx791s2i/stackoverflow.png?raw=1
```

Note that using **"?dl=1"** (instead of dl=0) will download the image.

Reference: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work while trying to address a similar problem by logging into Dropbox, viewing the image itself, right clicking on the image and selecting "Copy Image Address".